# How to save video recorded with camera package to gallery in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, caching, camera, gallery

I'm using the [camera package](https://pub.dev/packages/camera) to record videos in the app.
How can I save the recorded video to gallery, if it saves to the app cache directory?
I'm able to get the 'XFile' but I don't really know to how to go from there.

```
final file = await _cameraController.stopVideoRecording();
print(file.path); // /data/user/0/com.example/cache/REC804616628562956211.mp4
```

Also, should I then delete it from cache after copying the file? How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've managed to solve this myself.
I used [`gallery_saver` package](https://pub.dev/packages/gallery_saver) to save the recorded video to gallery. Then I can delete the video file from cache using dart:io.

```
final video = await _cameraController.stopVideoRecording();
await GallerySaver.saveVideo(video.path);
File(video.path).deleteSync();
```

Answer (score 0):

The above solution didn't quite work out for me. The recorded video got saved in my phone but not on my co-worker's phone. I would recommend the gallery_saver  and image_picker packages. You can check out the example here:
https://pub.dev/packages/gallery_saver

The video gets recorded and saved. With the camera plugin, I faced another issue where the video through the selfie camera got darkened.

Answer (score 0):

gallery_saver has not been maintained for two years already. I am just using [gal package](https://pub.dev/packages/gal) instead.

```dart
import 'package:gal/gal.dart';

await Gal.putVideo(path);
```